# Scroll to anchor from another page

Tags: jquery, html, css

The issue is it works fine on the local environment. But when I publish it to `surge` it does not work properly. I am using `webpack` for both `dev` and `prod`.

**Update**
I published the website again. This solution sometime works sometime not. Testing in Chrome Incognito. Is there any issue of caching ? After clicking few links on website, scroll to anchor started working properly.

I am using below code:

```
$("a[href^='#']").on('click', function(event) {

        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          var hash = this.hash;
          var header = $('.rd-navbar').height();

          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - header
          }, 800, function(){

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        }
      });
```

Smooth scrolling works fine if the anchor is on the same page. But for example, I've got a footer where the link is `technology.html#security`. This works fine in my local environment. But when I click on the same link on the published version it does not scroll to the `security` section on `technology.html`.

I am also using below `CSS`:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}    
section:before {
        height: 40px;
        content: "";
        display:block;
    }
```

Also if I refresh the page `technology.html#security` on local, it works fine and scrolls properly to the section. But not on published version.

**How do fix scrolling to anchor on another page on production ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scroll to anchor after loading new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293784/smooth-scroll-to-anchor-after-loading-new-page)

Comment: @AswinKumar already tried but didn't work for me. The issue is on production version.

Comment: What didn't work ? did you check the hash and the associated element  ? This method passing #hash should works.

Comment: Are you sure the animation code is also located in the target page?

Comment: @samb102 it works fine on local env. it doesn't work on prod env.

Comment: @AswinKumar jquery code is in common script.

Comment: @Valay Maybe the script takes some time to load. try placing it inline

Comment: @AswinKumar it's common code for all `<a>`.

Comment: @Valay click event works only onclick only. your code need to be in $(function() {});

Comment: @AswinKumar code is in `$document.ready()`

Comment: @Valay is it possible to provide me in fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188901/discussion-between-aswin-kumar-and-valay).